# Cufon capitalize words with üäëö

Tags: css, cufon

Cufon works great for my menu but when it comes to capitalize entries like "über uns" the result is "ÜBer Uns".

Anyone aware on how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to the development version as per [this site.](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cufon/rZjITFQ22-Y)

In the development version the regex is different:

```
@@ -210,7 +210,7 @@ var Cufon = (function() {
           return s.toLowerCase();
         },
         capitalize: function(s) {
-          return s.replace(/\b./g, function($0) {
+          return s.replace(/(?:^|\s)./g, function($0) {
             return $0.toUpperCase();
           });
         }
```

Source: https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/commit/b64768265b51efc0d4de220482173f4c33491c15